# Caching HTTP files with PHP

Tags: php, httpclient, http-caching

I'm writing a library that requests files via HTTP and HTTPS. To reduce traffic to often requested URLs, I want to cache the retrieved files and respect their cache settings.

Now the cache expiry seems to be a hard thing, because the [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) define so many of them that need to be checked in all possible combinations:

- `Expires`
- `Cache-Control` (with dozens of possible values)
- `Pragma`

I can imagine that someone already wrote PHP code that implements all that stuff correctly. Where is it?

Comment: I have a feeling that PHP is not the best way to cache files. I'd try to find a solution baked into the server, or a caching proxy. Here's [Apache's Caching Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html).

Comment: grossvogel, that's unfortunately not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right: somebody's already done that :)

PHP framework [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/) comes with a [caching reverse proxy](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/http_cache.html) as part of its standard distribution. Docs here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/http_cache.html

Answer (score 3):

Using a Reverse Proxy like Squid, Varnish or even Apache mod_cache would help you a lot regarding cache related HTTP headers. However if you need to have a full PHP version you should honor Cache-Control and then Expires because when Cache-Control and Expires are available in the same HTTP response Cache-Control takes precedence with the "max-age" attribute as described in http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3:

> If a response includes both an Expires header and a max-age directive, the max-age
>   directive overrides the Expires header, even if the Expires header is more restrictive.
>   This rule allows an origin server to provide, for a given response, a longer expiration
>   time to an HTTP/1.1 (or later) cache than to an HTTP/1.0 cache. This might be useful if
>   certain HTTP/1.0 caches improperly calculate ages or expiration times, perhaps due to
>   desynchronized clocks.

You should also be very careful with the "no-cache" attribute which is kind of misleading as it requires a revalidation with the origin server, so it is a bit like a "store-but-do-no-serve-from-cache-without-revalidation" header.

You can also ignore the Pragma header for two reasons:

- it is a request header, not a response header
- it is for HTTP 1.0 and the (almost entire) world is HTTP 1.1 now :)

'Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org) with [HTTP Cache Plugin](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/plugins/cache-plugin.html) would be the best solution IMO.